# Truffle Console 'from' Parameter Ignored

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle

I have this payable fallback function in a contract code:

```
function() is_live() payable {
        if (msg.value == 0) throw;
        if (isFinalized) throw;

        uint256 tokens = safeMult(msg.value, tokenExchangeRate);   // calculate num of tokens purchased
        uint256 checkedSupply = safeAdd(totalSupply, tokens);      // calculate total supply if purchased

        if (maxCap < checkedSupply) throw;                         // if exceeding token max, cancel order

        totalSupply = checkedSupply;                               // update totalSupply
        balances[msg.sender] += tokens;                            // update token balance for payer
        MPYCreation(msg.sender, tokens);                           // logs token creation event
    }
```

In `truffle console` I execute the command:

```
Token.send(500, {from: web3.eth.accounts[1]})
```

(Where `Token` refers to the contract instance)

But then I check `web3.eth.accounts[0]` and `web3.eth.accounts[1]` balances and **0** has paid the weis, while **1** has a balance of 10 ether.

How is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: To call the fallback of your contract use `eth.sendTransaction({ to: "0xContractAddress", from: web3.eth.accounts[1], value: web3.toWei(1, "ether") })`

Comment: @Ismael make it an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call the fallback of your contract you have to [send a transaction](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction), a low level way of doing this is the following:

```
var amount = web3.toWei(1, "ether");
var account = web3.eth.accounts[1];
var contractAddress = "0xContractAddress";
eth.sendTransaction({ to: contractAddress, from: account, value: amount });
```